# ggplot error in is.finite(x) and doesnt know how to pick scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with a scatter plot in ggplot. Understand that ggplot does not like data in a list but when I check the class it is a data frame. The errors I am getting are

```
Dont know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

My data I want to scatter plot is:

```
       Risk        Reward
NCM 0.02546471  0.0001596743
TLS 0.01288961  0.0002183247
CCL 0.01510990  0.0002710004
WOW 0.01270629  0.0002937180
MVF 0.02302660  -0.0002582542
```

code

`ggplot(riskreward, aes(x = risk, y = reward))+ geom_point()`

If it worked it should appear like this (created in excel)
[Scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF303.png)

Comment: hard to tell without knowing what your data is like ... can you edit your qiestion with the results of `dput(riskreward)` please. Also note that your variables seem to be called `Risk` & `Reward` but you use `risk` and `reward` in the ggplot call -- although this wouldn't give this error

Comment: okay, I can reproduce the error with `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mtcars["wt"], y=mpg)) + geom_point()`  ... so really need to see what your data looks like to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your dataframe table as follows (I assume you already have it)

```
df <- data.frame(numeric(), numeric())

df <- rbind(df, c(0.02546471, 0.0001596743))
df <- rbind(df, c(0.01288961, 0.0002183247))
df <- rbind(df, c(0.01510990, 0.0002710004))
df <- rbind(df, c(0.01270629, 0.0002937180))
df <- rbind(df, c(0.02302660, -0.0002582542))

colnames(df) <- c("Risk", "Reward")
```

The best library to plot graphs by far is ggplot2. It gives a wide range of customization options for your plots.

So you can import ggplot2 and run the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Risk, y = Reward))+ geom_point()+
  xlim(0, 0.03)+
  ylim(-0.0003, 0.0004)+
  theme_classic()
```

You will get an output like:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Setting manual breaks, labels and limits can get you what you want. Here is one example:

```r
options(scipen=10000)
base <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Risk, y = Reward))+ geom_point()
base + scale_y_continuous(labels = c("-0.0003","-0.0002","-0.0001","0","0.0001","0.0002","0.0003", "0.0004"), breaks = c(-0.0003,-0.0002,-0.0001,0,0.0001,0.0002,0.0003, 0.0004), limits = c(-0.00035,.0004)) +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.005,0.01,0.015,0.02,0.025,0.03), labels = c("0","0.005","0.01","0.015","0.02","0.025","0.03"), limits = c(0,0.031))
```

## Output

[image: scale_out]